# Retrieve positive or negative n bits from unsigned char ( Little endian )

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

How would I retrieve negative value from unsigned char.

Say I have  unsigned char which I passed into fun and just want to get 1st 6bits. Now these 6bits can have positive or negative value populated from some other function. I want to extract same value .
I can successfully extract positive value using 0x3F. But how about if it has negative value example

```
signed char my_6bitfunc(  unsigned char *val )
{
   unsigned char temp = *val & 0x3F;
   return temp;
}

// somewhere in main
 int main()
{
    signed char valneg = -31 ;
    signed char valpos = 31 ;

   signed char a = my_6bitfunc( &valneg );
    signed char b = my_6bitfunc( &valpos );

    printf("  val neg %d\n", a );  // not -31 but 33 ?
    printf(" val positive %d\n", b );
}
```

**o/p**
expected value for a = -31 actual value = 33 why ?  Wrong
expected value for b  = 31 actual value = 31 Correct.

Comment: In `my_6bitfunc` why is `temp` `unsigned`?

Comment: @MotKohn,even signed doesnt make any difference. I am returning signed char.  I think what I am looking here is extra operation like xor or something like that which gives me expected value but have no clue wht to add

Comment: What result do you want if the function is called with -75 ?

Comment: @4386427 re. 2's complement, then something like `(unsigned char)~(i - 1)`

Comment: @4386427 - 75 is more than 6 bits so code dnt care. Max vaue posiitve should only be 63 i think if we take unsigned 6 bit

Comment: For a signed value, the first bit will determine if the value is negative or not. So, for characters `(128 & temp) == 128` or `temp >> 7`. This is not portable, but will probably work for your case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To sign extend a twos complement field, use `((x ^ N) - N)` -- where `N` is the numeric representation of the sign bit, e.g., 32768 for 16 bits.

```
signed char my_6bitfunc (unsigned char *val)
{
   unsigned char temp = *val & 0x3FU;
   return ((signed char )(temp ^ 0x20U)) - 0x20;
}
```

Comment: I did similar thing   temp =  ( temp ^ 0x20 ) - 0x20; and now get expected value. But still cant understand  why we xor it and subtract and how I get correct value? for example 0x3D XOR 0x20 = 0x1F( 31 in dec ) . Now 1F- 0X20 ? ... I know Iam getting correct value but could you please explain it to me

Comment: In continuation . When i substract 1F-0x20 in calculator I get 111111111111. How does return signed temp make it correct?

Comment: 0x20 is the sign bit; you can think of it as having a value of -2^5 whereas the other bits have value 2^4 2^3 ... 2^0. The XOR inverts the sign bit, bit 5; if it was zero, we've added 2^5; if it was one, we've subtracted 2^5. Now by subtracting 2^5 we restore the 2^5 we added in if the sign bit was zero, and subtracted out the 2^5 we need to for twos complement if the sign bit was one.

Comment: Thanks for explaination

Comment: Note that `111111111111` is the twos-complement representation for -1, which is what you'd expect for `0x1F- 0x20`.  Try adding -2^5 + 2^4 + 2^3 + 2^2 + 2^1 + 2^0 (where ^ here means "to the power of", not XOR as it does in C).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't just mask away the 2 upper bits for negative numbers.

Why not?

Well, in 2's complement and 8 bit char variable (which is most common), you have:

```
-31 -> 11100001
```

If you mask by 0x3f you'll get

```
00100001
```

which is exactly 33 for an 8 bit 2's complement signed number. Consequently, your program prints 33.

In general you can't play around with the basic representation of numbers in the computer. On most systems there is no way to represent a signed number in 6 bits and print it using an 8 bit format. It is just not possible.

However, you can write a function that limits the range of an 8 bit signed number to 6 bit signed number. The C standard gives you a clue to how that could be done when converting between types with different numbers of bits. You could implement a similar conversion.

A 6 bit signed 2's complement number can hold -32 to 31. So if the input to your conversion function -75 you shall keep adding 31+1 (i.e. MAX+1) to the input until it is within the valid range.

```
-75 + (31+1) = -43 
-43 + (31+1) = -11 (which is in range)
```

But at the binary level you will need to save it as `11110101` as your computer most likely uses 8 bit as its smallest integer type.

If you know that the range of **negative** input is between -32 and -1 (and don't care for conversions when input is less than -32), you can leave the binary pattern unchanged for negative numbers. Like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

signed char my_6bitfunc(  signed char *val )
{
    if (*val < 0) return *val;  // Add this line
    return *val & 0x3F;;
}

 int main()
{
    signed char valneg = -31 ;
    signed char valpos = 31 ;

    signed char a = my_6bitfunc( &valneg );
    signed char b = my_6bitfunc( &valpos );

    printf("  val neg %d\n", a );  // not -31 but 33 ?
    printf(" val positive %d\n", b );
}
```

Output:

```
  val neg -31
 val positive 31
```

Comment: All I am interested in is 6bit has negative and positive value populated by some func. other mSb is filled by other functions. SO I need to extract 1st 6bits with signed and unsigned val